# How can I turn the android screen on and unlock it with WakeLock?

Tags: android, wakelock, unlock

I have a service that runs in background with PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK. It waits until someone shakes the device (using the accelerometer) and then turns the screen on and start an activity.
I use this piece of code to unlock the screen:

```
        PowerManager TempPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock TempWakeLock = TempPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "TempWakeLock");
        TempWakeLock.acquire();

        // do the work that needs the visible display...
```

It works pretty fine so far, but is there any way I could make the phone unlock itself once the screen is on, so that the user doesn't have to slide it manually or to write his password?

I tried using this:

```
        mKeyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        mLock = mKeyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock("activity_classname");
        mLock.disableKeyguard();
```

However, I get this weird bug and the variable name is stroked...

```
        The type KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock is deprecated
        Add @SuppressWarnings 'deprecation' to 'mLock'
```

I dunno even if this is the correct solution, but it isn't working...
Does anyone know what I should do?

To sum up, I intend to make a service that unlocks the screen, so that the user doesn't have to slide it or write his password, and then starts an activity... Any ideas??

Thank you!

Comment: Your bug is just a warning. Also, you can't bypass a password / gesture / whatever protected lockscreen. That would ruin the whole idea behind it.

Comment: Yep, it works. So, basically, it can only unlock the phone when there's no password? Isn't there any other way I could make it bypass the password also?